# Find Element using Protractor ( Click on login button)

Tags: protractor

How do I find element in Protractor to click on a button (login button).... I have entered login name and Password but no luck clicking on my "log in" button. My code does not have model, Repeater , ID or class for the login section to enter the App.
Thanks in advance for the help. Ho do I format the actual code so I can run this using Protratcor?

Following is my code:

```
<div class="btn-panel">
div>
<div ng-show="loginAsAdmin" hs-gesture="{handler: goToPin}" class="ng-hide">
<i class="icon-back-round"></i>
</div>
!--<div class="brad-all attention" hs-gesture="{handler: clearLogin}">
 i class="icon-close-round"></i>
 </div>-->
 <div class="btn-ok" hs-gesture="{handler: doSubscribe}" localize="(!canSubscribe || loginAsAdmin) ? 'Log In' : 'Subscribe'">Log In</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div ng-show="loginAsAdmin" hs-gesture="{handler: goToPin}" class="ng-hide">
 <i class="icon-back-round"></i>
 </div>
<div class="btn-ok" hs-gesture="{handler: doSubscribe}" localize="(!canSubscribe || loginAsAdmin) ? 'Log In' : 'Subscribe'">Log In</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit for future users** *(This command was a workaround rather than a direct solution to his original problem of not finding/clicking button)*:

You could also try submitting the form by hitting enter (you may want to do this while within the password field) - `browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();`

**Another Edit:** This also just occurred to me - there is another option to simulate a click event: `browser.driver.actions().mouseDown(loginBtn).mouseUp().perform();`

**Original Post**

You say your code does not have an ID or class, but I see your Login links having the class 'btn-ok'?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding but you could try using cssContainingText:

```
var loginBtn = element(by.cssContainingText('.btn-ok', 'Log In');
loginBtn.click();
```

That will locate the element with a class of 'btn-ok' with the specified string of 'Log In'

Source: https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gunderson:  I tried it but it did not click on the "login" button... It did not give me any error either. The the test passed but it did not do what it was suppose to.

Comment: @Kevin Hmm ok.  It looks like you have two <div> elements both with the same class and containing the string 'Log In' - so maybe that's the issue?  See if this helps:
`var loginBtn = element.all(by.cssContainingText('.btn-ok', 'Log In').first();`

If thats not the right element, switch `.first()` with `.last()` and see if that helps.  Also, are you positive it isn't clicking?  A passing test could simply be a wrong assertion/expect statement.

Comment: Ignore that last part of my comment, any failures to click are almost certainly a result of improper element locators (you're either finding more than 1 element and it's clicking on the wrong one, or you're finding none at all)

Comment: I tried both recommendation but no luck.. what I see is that the cursor comes out of the "Password" field but I just do not see the login button being clicked.. I put a pause after all the commands get executed but I do not see my app being logged into. Also what I notice is that (Maybe) a double click is needed here... is it right to put loginBtn.click(); twice for a double click??

Comment: I can't remember the exact scenario but I have certainly called click twice on an element before.  Might as well try it, make sure it's two separate calls as in: `loginBtn.click();`  `loginBtn.click();` (as opposed to `loginBtn.click().click()`)

Comment: Another possibility - try hitting the enter key?  You might want to do this while inside the password field still.  `browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();`   If all else fails, my only other suggestion would be to add an ID to those login buttons if possible.

Comment: Still not working.. I will work on it more... Thanks for your time anyway

Comment: That did it.. using the following command caused the login button to be clicked and enter the application. Could you explain what just happened considering this command did NOT use any attributes from the "Log In" button: Thanks a lot Gunderson --------                                                                                                                                                                                    browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();

Comment: @Kevin Awesome, glad it worked.  I'm not familiar with Angular forms necessarily, but its somewhat standard for forms to have a `type="submit"` attribute that is called when a User clicks enter (the same action would be called if they clicked the Log In button) unless the Submit-on-enter functionality has specifically been disabled within that browser or by the developer.  It's possible that this won't work across all browsers for you - so it's still ideal to try and get that login button to actually be clicked.

Comment: It didn't need any attributes from the Log In button because it wasn't directly interacting with that element.  However I added one final idea to the answer above (the mouseDown.mouseUp one) - and this would be preferable because it would actually simulate a click event on the button

Comment: I tried the command that included the mouseDwon.mouseUp but id didn't do the click on the button... No failure was reported

Answer (score 0):

@kevin Presuming that

`' <div class="btn-ok" hs-gesture="{handler: doSubscribe}" localize="(!canSubscribe || loginAsAdmin) ? 'Log In' : 'Subscribe'">Log In</div>
 </div>'`

is the tag that holds the your login button and also only clicking is what you need. following might work for you:

`element(by.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'btn-ok') and contains(text(),'Log In')]")).click();`

Comment: Thanks for reply Murali... I tried it but it did not click on the "login" button... No errors were reported

Answer (score 0):

You can select it by className using `element(by.className('btn-ok'))` or `element(by.css('.btn-ok'))` and then simply throw a `.click()` on the end and voila:

`element(by.css('.btn-ok')).click();` or `$('.btn-ok').click()`